# How to change OpenGL Version using QGLFormat on MacOS?

Tags: python, macos, opengl, pyqt4, qglwidget

I'm using PyOpenGL on a Mac. By default, OpenGL 2.1 is used. However, according to my research and to OpenGL Extension Viewer, I should be able to use OpenGL 4.1.
I'm trying to pass a QGLFormat to my QGLWidget, as I've seen done on many threads here, but the context version does not change. If I try to force it, it tells me that the context is not valid.
I have been experimenting a lot - here is a very simple example that shows my problem:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, QtOpenGL
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    glFormat = QtOpenGL.QGLFormat()
    glFormat.setVersion(4,1)
    glFormat.setProfile(QtOpenGL.QGLFormat.CoreProfile)
    glFormat.setSampleBuffers(True)
    glFormat.setDefaultFormat(glFormat)
    print("Format version: " + str(glFormat.majorVersion()))
    myW = QtOpenGL.QGLWidget(glFormat)
    print ("Widget context valid: " + str(myW.context().isValid()))
    print ("Widget format version: " + str(myW.format().majorVersion()))
    print ("Widget context format version: " + str(myW.context().format().majorVersion()))
    myW.context().setFormat(glFormat)
    print ("Forced format valid: " + str(myW.context().isValid()))
    print ("Forced format version: " + str(myW.format().majorVersion()))
    myW.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is the output:

```
Format version: 4
Widget context valid: True
Widget format version: 1
Widget context format version: 1
Forced format valid: False
Forced format version: 4
```

Any idea where my problem lies? Am I doing something wrong?
I'm using macOS Sierra version 10.12.6.
I use Qt version 4.8.7, sip version 4.19.3, and pyqt version 4.12, in case that's relevant.
Here is [what OpenGL Extension Viewer tells me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4i0Q.png).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit**:

I found what looks like a similar problem with C++ here. I'm not sure how to translate the solution to PyQt, but I will look into this:
[Changing the OpenGL Context Version for QGLWidgets in Qt 4.8.6 on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24873533).

**Edit 3**:

I get the following output when trying (the second version of) the patch provided by @ekhumoro:

```
patching file qpy/QtOpenGL/core_profile_attributes.mm
patching file qpy/QtOpenGL/qpyopengl.pro
patching file sip/QtOpenGL/qgl.sip
patch unexpectedly ends in middle of line
Hunk #3 FAILED at 493.
1 out of 3 hunks FAILED -- saving rejects to file sip/QtOpenGL/qgl.sip.rej
```

qpyopengl.pro is patched correctly now, but it still fails for qgl.sip.

**Update**:

Here is the content of the reject file for qgl.sip:

```
***************
*** 478,481 ****

  %ModuleHeaderCode
  #include <qpyopengl_api.h>

--- 493,498 ----

  %ModuleHeaderCode
  #include <qpyopengl_api.h>
+ typedef struct GDevice** GDHandle;
+ void* select_3_2_mac_visual();
```

Out of curiosity, I ran configure-ng.py and tried to compile. I get the following error:

```
[...]/PyQt4_gpl_mac-4.12.1/sip/QtOpenGL/qgl.sip:269:5: error: 'virtual' can only appear on non-static member functions
    virtual void* chooseMacVisual(GDHandle handle)
    ^
[...]/PyQt4_gpl_mac-4.12.1/sip/QtOpenGL/qgl.sip:271:16: error: use of undeclared identifier 'select_3_2_mac_visual'
        return select_3_2_mac_visual();
               ^
[...]/PyQt4_gpl_mac-4.12.1/sip/QtOpenGL/qgl.sip:269:44: warning: unused parameter 'handle' [-Wunused-parameter]
    virtual void* chooseMacVisual(GDHandle handle)
```

Comment: You'll need to create a _forward-compatible_ context on OSX.

Comment: @derhass: Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

For what it is worth, running your code on my Windows 10 laptop gives the following output:

```
Format version: 4
Widget context valid: True
Widget format version: 4
Widget context format version: 4
Forced format valid: False
Forced format version: 4
```

Therefore, I suspect that your issue might not actually be a platform-specific one, but rather with your `myW.context().setFormat(glFormat)` call. Interestingly, I took a look at the [PyQt documentation for QGLWidget](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qglwidget.html) and it appears to be missing for setFormat(), which is pretty unhelpful!

Looking instead at the corresponding **C++ documentation**, it looks like `setFormat()` can actually be called from **either** the [QGLWidget itself](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qglwidget-obsolete.html#setFormat), or it child [QGLContext](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qglcontext.html#setFormat) object. Since you are calling it from the `QGLContext`, it turns out that the context is **reset**, making it invalid. The solution is to call `myW.context().create()` after setting the format, thus creating a valid format object with the new parameters! That modification would look like this:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, QtOpenGL
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    glFormat = QtOpenGL.QGLFormat()
    glFormat.setVersion(4,1)
    glFormat.setProfile(QtOpenGL.QGLFormat.CoreProfile)
    glFormat.setSampleBuffers(True)
    glFormat.setDefaultFormat(glFormat)
    print("Format version: " + str(glFormat.majorVersion()))
    myW = QtOpenGL.QGLWidget(glFormat)
    print ("Widget context valid: " + str(myW.context().isValid()))
    print ("Widget format version: " + str(myW.format().majorVersion()))
    print ("Widget context format version: " + str(myW.context().format().majorVersion()))
    myW.context().setFormat(glFormat)
    myW.context().create()
    print ("Forced format valid: " + str(myW.context().isValid()))
    print ("Forced format version: " + str(myW.format().majorVersion()))
    myW.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The other alternative is to just call `setFormat()` at the `QGLWidget` level, which **automatically creates a new context**, resulting in this:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, QtOpenGL
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    glFormat = QtOpenGL.QGLFormat()
    glFormat.setVersion(4,1)
    glFormat.setProfile(QtOpenGL.QGLFormat.CoreProfile)
    glFormat.setSampleBuffers(True)
    glFormat.setDefaultFormat(glFormat)
    print("Format version: " + str(glFormat.majorVersion()))
    myW = QtOpenGL.QGLWidget(glFormat)
    print ("Widget context valid: " + str(myW.context().isValid()))
    print ("Widget format version: " + str(myW.format().majorVersion()))
    print ("Widget context format version: " + str(myW.context().format().majorVersion()))
    myW.setFormat(glFormat)
    print ("Forced format valid: " + str(myW.context().isValid()))
    print ("Forced format version: " + str(myW.format().majorVersion()))
    myW.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

That being said, **all of this is conjecture since I do not have a Mac on which I can test this code.** Let me know if this fixes the problem for you, and hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! At least, I know why the context becomes invalid, thanks to you.
Actually, I already tried calling setFormat() at the widget level, but it does not change anything: that is, the context is valid, but the version stays 1. This is why I was trying directly on the context. :(
I tried your first suggestion as well, but I get the same result: I end up with a valid context, but still the wrong OpenGL version.

Comment: @Elensil Took a look at that link you added in the question edit. If upgrading to PyQt5 is not an option (which might fix your issue), it looks like you need to translate that C++ option somehow. There are a bunch of options (ctypes, cython, or C extensions) but the simplest will probably be getting it to work with ctypes first. Hopefully adding a bounty will bring some attention to this question, since I cannot really test anything out without a Mac lol...

Comment: I tried with PyQt5, it fixes the problem. It's a backup solution, but upgrading my application to PyQt5 will take a big amount of work.
Mostly because there is a bit of legacy OpenGL thrown in the mix, that does not work anymore when I switch to PyQt5. 
I'm not the original developper, and I have limited knowledge of OpenGL and its different versions.
On the other hand, I want something easy to install for my users. Downloading and running patches might discourage more than a few. :(

Comment: @Elensil Define what you mean by legacy code. Is there fixed-function stuff like `glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES)`, display lists, or calls like `glTranslate` to a transformation stack? What version shaders are you using (e.g. `#version120`)? It is possible that you might not need a modern opengl context at all if you are targeting functionality that has been deprecated in OpenGL. Also, if you go the Qt5 route, keep in mind that `QGLWidget` is actually [not recommended in new code](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qglwidget.html).

Comment: Yes, I already replaced all my `QGLWidget` by `QOpenGLWidget` and so on. It seems I got that part working. There are indeed some fixed-function stuff like `glBegin`. For my shaders, I'm not sure what version I use. I leave the version unspecified, but I use qualifiers like `varying/uniform/attribute`. With PyQt5, it forces me to specify the version. Version 120 is not supported, so I tried with 330 by changing the qualifiers, but I still have a `undeclared identifier 'gl_Vertex'`. I'm trying to figure out how to use a vertex buffer. I will get there eventually.

Comment: @Elensil `varying/uniform/attribute` are all part of the GLSL 120 spec and have been replaced by the keywords `in/out`. Similarly, there no longer is support for pre-defined variables like `gl_Vertex` and `gl_ProjectionMatrix` for example; those have to be replaced by passing in your own custom attributes and uniforms. I would take a look at [this](https://learnopengl.com/) series of OpenGL tutorials; I have found them really helpful for understanding the more modern side of OpenGL. Good luck, and I am sure you will get there eventually too!

Answer (score 1):

To answer the specific question regarding translating the Mac-specific solution into Python: this is not possible to do *directly*, because the PyQt bindings do not wrap the virtual method [chooseMacVisual](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qglcontext.html#chooseMacVisual). Without this, there is no way to reimplement it, because Qt just cannot see any Python methods that PyQt has not pre-defined as being virtual.

So the only way to get it to work will be to patch PyQt4 and re-compile it. Fortunately, someone has already done this, and provided the code here:

- https://github.com/prideout/coregl-python

However, the build instructions aren't entirely clear, and are aimed at PyQt-4.9.4. So I have prepared a diff which should be easier to work with. I have not attempted to compile it because I don't have access to a Mac system.

To apply the patch, unpack the [latest PyQt4 OSX sources](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download), and cd into the directory. Then copy the diff below and save it as `macgl.diff`, and run this command:

```
patch -Np1 -i macgl.diff
```

You can then compile your patched PyQt4 using the instructions shown here:

- [Installing PyQt4](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/installation.html)

**UPDATE**:

I previously thought a diff against PyQt-4.9.4 would apply cleanly against all newer PyQt4 versions, but I was wrong about that. I have attempted to remedy this with the revised diff below, which has been adapted for the [PyQt-4.12.1 mac source code](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt4/PyQt-4.12.1/PyQt4_gpl_mac-4.12.1.tar.gz/download).

Here is the diff:

```
diff -Naur c/qpy/QtOpenGL/core_profile_attributes.mm d/qpy/QtOpenGL/core_profile_attributes.mm
--- c/qpy/QtOpenGL/core_profile_attributes.mm   1970-01-01 01:00:00.000000000 +0100
+++ d/qpy/QtOpenGL/core_profile_attributes.mm   2017-10-22 20:11:53.000000000 +0100
@@ -0,0 +1,22 @@
+#include <QGLContext>
+ 
+ 
+void* select_3_2_mac_visual()
+{
+    static const int Max = 40;
+    NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute attribs[Max];
+    int cnt = 0;
+   
+    attribs[cnt++] = NSOpenGLPFAOpenGLProfile;
+    attribs[cnt++] = NSOpenGLProfileVersion3_2Core;
+   
+    attribs[cnt++] = NSOpenGLPFADoubleBuffer;
+   
+    attribs[cnt++] = NSOpenGLPFADepthSize;
+    attribs[cnt++] = (NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute)16;
+   
+    attribs[cnt] = 0;
+    Q_ASSERT(cnt < Max);
+   
+    return [[NSOpenGLPixelFormat alloc] initWithAttributes:attribs];
+}
diff -Naur c/qpy/QtOpenGL/qpyopengl.pro d/qpy/QtOpenGL/qpyopengl.pro
--- c/qpy/QtOpenGL/qpyopengl.pro    2017-06-30 09:47:26.000000000 +0100
+++ d/qpy/QtOpenGL/qpyopengl.pro    2017-10-31 17:07:37.694805459 +0000
@@ -24,6 +24,11 @@
 TARGET      = qpyopengl
 TEMPLATE    = lib

+mac {
+     OBJECTIVE_SOURCES  +=  core_profile_attributes.mm
+     LIBS += -framework Foundation -framework Cocoa
+ }
+
 SOURCES   = \
             qpyopengl_attribute_array.cpp \
             qpyopengl_uniform_value_array.cpp
diff -Naur c/sip/QtOpenGL/qgl.sip d/sip/QtOpenGL/qgl.sip
--- c/sip/QtOpenGL/qgl.sip  2017-06-30 09:47:26.000000000 +0100
+++ d/sip/QtOpenGL/qgl.sip  2017-10-31 17:30:26.025295693 +0000
@@ -20,6 +20,14 @@
 // WARRANTY OF DESIGN, MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.


+%ModuleCode
+#include <qgl.h>
+
+typedef struct GDevice** GDHandle;
+void* select_3_2_mac_visual();
+
+%End
+
 namespace QGL
 {
 %TypeHeaderCode
@@ -257,6 +265,13 @@
 %End
 %End

+%TypeCode
+    virtual void* chooseMacVisual(GDHandle handle)
+    {
+        return select_3_2_mac_visual();
+    }
+%End
+
 public:
     void deleteTexture(GLuint tx_id);
     static void setTextureCacheLimit(int size);
@@ -478,4 +493,6 @@

 %ModuleHeaderCode
 #include <qpyopengl_api.h>
+typedef struct GDevice** GDHandle;
+void* select_3_2_mac_visual();
 %End
```

Comment: This looks great, thanks for the thorough answer! I have no way to test this out either, so hopefully the OP can reply and verify that it works on the newer version of PyQt4.

Comment: @CodeSurgeon. Looks like we're all in the dark here on this one, but hopefully the patch will still work...

Comment: @ekhumoro
Thanks for the answer, this looks promising!
I've been away for some time and just got back on the problem.
Just to be clear, your patch completely replaces the coregl-python link you provided, right?
I tried your instructions, but I get an error message (see my second edit in the question). Any idea what causes this?
Unfortunately, I'm just blindly following your instructions here, and I'm not much help.

Comment: @Elensil. Yes, it completely replaces it. However, it seems I somehow did not test the patch properly against PyQt-4.12.1, because I'm now finding it only applies cleanly against PyQt-4.9.4. I have now updated my answer with a revised patch for PyQt-4.12.1 - but, as with the first one, I have no idea whether it will actually compile properly, as I don't have access to a mac.

Comment: @ekhumoro. Thanks! I tried your patch again, I still get an error (see the question for details). Do you think you can fix it?

Comment: @Elensil. I tested it again with PyQt4_gpl_mac-4.12.1 and it works fine for me. Are you sure you copied the diff properly? The error message seems to suggest you didn't. The compiler output doesn't look very promising, though. It seems to suggest that the patch isn't going to be forward-compatible.

Comment: Yes, I just checked twice. I tried adding a new line after the last `%End`. I get two `unexpectedly ends in middle of line` but no failure message. When I compile, the second error disappear, but I still get the first one :(

Comment: @Elensil. It's hard to see how that can happen - I thought `patch` worked the same way on all unix systems. Can you please post the rejects file?

Comment: I copied the reject file's content in the question.
In the end, I'm trying to upgrade my application to PyQt5 in the meantime.
But still, it would be nice to solve the issue, and your patch will probably be useful for others!

Comment: @Elensil. It must be a line-endings issue. Make sure the diff file ends with a newline, and that the last line is completely empty (no whitespace). (PS: I think your decision to bite the bullet and port to PyQt5 is the right one. Qt4 is unsupported legacy code now, so the sooner you can move away from it, the better).